# Apache Flink Job cluster rpc.address binding to localhost on kubernetes

Tags: java, kubernetes, akka, apache-flink

I'm trying to run Flink Job cluster(1.8.1) in kubernetes environment. I created docker image with my Job jar using [this doc](https://github.com/apache/flink/tree/release-1.7/flink-container/docker).

Following [`kubefiles`](https://github.com/apache/flink/tree/release-1.7/flink-container/kubernetes) to create job, jobmanager and task manager. Issue is task manager is not able to connect to Job manager and keep crashing.

Upon debugging job manager logs, `jobmanager.rpc.address` is binding to "localhost".

But I have passed the args in kube files as per 
[this doc](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/release-1.7/flink-container/kubernetes/job-cluster-job.yaml.template#L34).

I also tried setting `jobmanager.rpc.address` in env variable(`FLINK_ENV_JAVA_OPTS`).

```
  env:
          - name: FLINK_ENV_JAVA_OPTS
            value: "-Djobmanager.rpc.address=flink-job-cluster"
```

**Job manager console log:**

```
Starting the job-cluster
Starting standalonejob as a console application on host flink-job-cluster-bbxrn.
2019-07-16 17:31:10,759 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         - --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2019-07-16 17:31:10,760 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -  Starting StandaloneJobClusterEntryPoint (Version: <unknown>, Rev:4caec0d, Date:03.04.2019 @ 13:25:54 PDT)
2019-07-16 17:31:10,760 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -  OS current user: flink
2019-07-16 17:31:10,761 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -  Current Hadoop/Kerberos user: <no hadoop dependency found>
2019-07-16 17:31:10,761 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -  JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM - IcedTea - 1.8/25.212-b04
2019-07-16 17:31:10,761 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -  Maximum heap size: 989 MiBytes
2019-07-16 17:31:10,761 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -  JAVA_HOME: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre
2019-07-16 17:31:10,761 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -  No Hadoop Dependency available
2019-07-16 17:31:10,761 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -  JVM Options:
2019-07-16 17:31:10,761 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -     -Xms1024m
2019-07-16 17:31:10,761 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -     -Xmx1024m
2019-07-16 17:31:10,762 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -     -Djobmanager.rpc.address=flink-job-cluster
2019-07-16 17:31:10,762 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -     -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/opt/flink-1.8.1/conf/log4j-console.properties
2019-07-16 17:31:10,762 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -     -Dlogback.configurationFile=file:/opt/flink-1.8.1/conf/logback-console.xml
2019-07-16 17:31:10,762 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -  Program Arguments:
2019-07-16 17:31:10,762 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -     --configDir
2019-07-16 17:31:10,762 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -     /opt/flink-1.8.1/conf
2019-07-16 17:31:10,762 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -     --job-classname
2019-07-16 17:31:10,762 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -     wikiedits.WikipediaAnalysis
2019-07-16 17:31:10,762 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -     --host
2019-07-16 17:31:10,762 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -     flink-job-cluster
2019-07-16 17:31:10,762 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -     -Djobmanager.rpc.address=flink-job-cluster
2019-07-16 17:31:10,763 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -     -Dparallelism.default=2
2019-07-16 17:31:10,763 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -     -Dblob.server.port=6124
2019-07-16 17:31:10,763 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -     -Dqueryable-state.server.ports=6125
2019-07-16 17:31:10,763 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -  Classpath: /opt/flink-1.8.1/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/opt/flink-1.8.1/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.15.jar:/opt/flink-1.8.1/lib/wiki-edits-0.1.jar:/opt/flink-1.8.1/lib/flink-dist_2.11-1.8.1.jar:::
2019-07-16 17:31:10,763 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         - --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2019-07-16 17:31:10,764 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         - Registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
2019-07-16 17:31:10,850 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: jobmanager.rpc.address, localhost
2019-07-16 17:31:10,851 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: jobmanager.rpc.port, 6123
2019-07-16 17:31:10,851 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: jobmanager.heap.size, 1024m
2019-07-16 17:31:10,851 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: taskmanager.heap.size, 1024m
2019-07-16 17:31:10,851 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots, 1
2019-07-16 17:31:10,851 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: parallelism.default, 1
```

Above logs shows `rpc.address` is binding to localhost instead of `flink-job-cluster`.

I assume task manager's messages are being dropped by Akka rpc as it binds to localhost:6123.

```
2019-07-16 17:31:12,546 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.StandaloneResourceManager  - Request slot with profile ResourceProfile{cpuCores=-1.0, heapMemoryInMB=-1, directMemoryInMB=0, nativeMemoryInMB=0, networkMemoryInMB=0} for job 38190f2570cd5f0a0a47f65ddf7aae1f with allocation id 97af00eae7e3dfb31a79232077ea7ee6.
2019-07-16 17:31:14,043 ERROR akka.remote.EndpointWriter                                    - dropping message [class akka.actor.ActorSelectionMessage] for non-local recipient [Actor[akka.tcp://flink@flink-job-cluster:6123/]] arriving at [akka.tcp://flink@flink-job-cluster:6123] inbound addresses are [akka.tcp://flink@localhost:6123]
2019-07-16 17:31:26,564 ERROR akka.remote.EndpointWriter                                    - dropping message [class akka.actor.ActorSelectionMessage] for non-local recipient [Actor[akka.tcp://flink@flink-job-cluster:6123/]] arriving at [akka.tcp://flink@flink-job-cluster:6123] inbound addresses are [akka.tcp://flink@localhost:6123]
```

Not sure why job manager binds to localhost.

PS: Task manager pod could resolve `flink-job-cluster` host. Hostname resolved to service ip address.

Answer (score 1):

Root cause of the issue is jobmanager.rpc.address arg value is not applied. Somehow [in-line Args](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/release-1.7/flink-container/kubernetes/job-cluster-job.yaml.template#L34) was not set into flink global configuration properly. But args passed as [multi-line list](https://gettaurus.org/docs/YAMLTutorial/#Lists-and-Dictionaries) works fine.